# Check whether all possible combinations from a list appear in an attribute of objects in another list

Tags: python, iteration

I have a bunch of tasks that need to be assigned in various combinations, and three people to give them to. There are various rules about which tasks can go together, but the gist is that there will always be exactly three tasks and each person must always be assigned exactly one of those tasks. I already have the code that will create a list of lists containing all possible combinations of three tasks that follow the rules:

```
lineups = [[Task1, Task2, Task3], [Task1, Task2, Task4],
           [Task1, Task2, Task5], [Task1, Task2, Task6], ...]
```

Each person is an instance of:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.office = ''
        self.tasks = []
```

where the `.tasks` attribute will store which tasks that person is able to perform. `people` is a simple list of `[Person1, Person2, Person3]`.

I've done quite a bit of searching and tried using `itertools.combinations` as well as `zip()` to try combining the two lists, but either those solutions don't give me the right output or I'm misunderstanding how to iterate over it.

**What I want to do is check all combinations of three `tasks` to make sure there is some lineup of `people` that can cover all three tasks with each `Person` having one `task`.** The point is that I don't want each `Person` to have to learn every `task` in the list, but need to be sure none of the legal combinations leave me with no one able to cover a task. If there are combinations that aren't covered, I want to build a list of those combinations so I can teach people new tasks to fix the problem.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing your additional questions, to focus at one problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have all the combinations of tasks that you want "covered" by your people. The simplest solution is to create the list of all combinations (a cross-product of all the list of skills from your people) and check whether each of your tasks combination is actually covered. Here is an attempt at it.

```
import itertools

tasks_combinations = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
people_tasks = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 4]]

people_tasks_product = map(set, (itertools.product(*people_tasks)))

for tasks_combination in tasks_combinations:
    if set(tasks_combination) in people_tasks_product:
        print('Task combination {} is covered.'.format(tasks_combination))
    else:
        print('Task combination {} is NOT covered.'.format(tasks_combination))
```

The issue with Evert's answer is that it does not cover the case where two people are complete retards and only one guy can do all the tasks for instance.

Comment: I can see this being what I need, but my test of it still isn't quite getting where I need to be. It's telling me that various combinations aren't covered even when I list every person as being able to perform every task, so there should be no chance of an uncovered lineup.

Comment: would you have an example of task combination not covered when every people can actually do the tasks used in that task combination ? Since I am using `set`, I am also assuming you don't have the same task repeated two times in a combination and that a combination always contains 3 items.

Comment: Part of the problem seems to have been me implementing it wrong. It no longer does that when every person contains all tasks. However, where `task_combinations = [[1, 2, 3,], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5]]`, `person1.tasks = [1]`, `person2.tasks = [2, 3, 4]`, and `person3.tasks = [2, 4, 5]`, it returns `[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5]` as not covered. When I change the order of the lists in `task_combinations`, that changes both which combinations show as uncovered and sometimes how many do.

Comment: you probably have an issue when building `people_tasks` everything runs smoothly if you have `people_tasks = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5]]`

Comment: I copied and pasted your original code into an otherwise empty script, changed `tasks_combinations` to include those six combinations, and changed to `people_tasks = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5]]`. The result is:
`Task combination [1, 2, 3] is covered.
Task combination [1, 2, 4] is covered.
Task combination [1, 2, 5] is NOT covered.
Task combination [1, 3, 4] is NOT covered.
Task combination [1, 3, 5] is NOT covered.
Task combination [1, 4, 5 is NOT covered.`

I don't understand why we'd be getting different results for identical code.

Comment: found the issue: Python 2 / 3 and `map`. You can use: `people_tasks_product = list(map(set, (itertools.product(*people_tasks))))` to solve it ;) moral of the story: python question should be tagged with the python version I think.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm still new enough not to have realized the version issue. Thanks for your help.